# JourneyBuilder Audience Rejection: Failed - ContactPreviouslyInSameInteraction

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, sql

I have an audience that was completely rejected in the activation stage.
Brand new Journey with a `no reentry` clause.

I have a support ticket in, but I'm wondering why this static audience would get rejected.  Here's the query I used to generate the audience (minus the column headers, for brevity purposes).

```
 SELECT x.*
FROM(

SELECT 
*columns here*

FROM ENT.[Organizations] ORG 
INNER JOIN ENT.[User_Organization] USRORG ON ORG.Id = USRORG.Organization_Id
INNER JOIN [Deliverable_Users] dusr ON USRORG.Contact_Key = dusr.Contact_Key
LEFT JOIN ENT.[Squadlockers] SL ON ORG.Id = SL.Organization_Id

WHERE 
Org.Logo IS NULL
AND
ORG.Status = 'active'
AND(
USRORG.Webmaster = 'true'
OR
USRORG.Registrar = 'true'
OR
USRORG.Financial = 'true'
OR
USRORG.Billing = 'true'
OR
USRORG.Admin = 'true'
)
) x
WHERE x.row = 1
```

Comment: Sometimes Audience gets rejected if an email address is not populated for them in the entry source.  Have you checked if your rejected contacts have email address populated in the entry source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out from support team that if you run a 'TEST' and have a no re-entry criteria set, that it won't inject those subscribers into the journey because they've already been through the test.

Seems like a major platform flaw since 'test' means I want to see if it works, not, I want to see if it works and also burn through this audience.

Solution is to either no test, or test and then duplicate journey, then activate.